# You are a failure of (a) human. -> why 'a'?

Tags: grammar, determiners

> You are a failure of human.
>
> You are a failure of a human.

Well, first, is putting 'a' in there grammatical? If so, what's the difference from when there's no 'a' there?

Comment: "Human" is a countable noun so the "a" is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are a [nounA] of a [nounB].

This is a very common way of saying things, where nounA is often things like *failure* or similar. It means:

> As a [nounB], you are a [nounA].

In this case,

> As a human, you are a failure.

You are a failure at being a human. It's a pretty weird thing to say.

You need the article because *human* is a singular countable noun here, so it needs some sort of determiner. If *human* is an adjective, as it sometimes is, obviously it doesn't need a determiner - but there's no way it can be an adjective here.